# iphone - How can i read the microphone input?

Tags: iphone, microphone

How can i read the sound data from the microphone?
I don't want to record and then access the data, i want to be able to access the sound input live?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by live sound data?  The mic output is analog, the ARM CPU is digital, and ADC chips have finite latency.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is to read the sound and send it to my server.
So let's say I am trying to use my iphone app as a voice chat client.

Comment: Hi @hotpaw2, I want to analyze the microphone data, can any documentation which will tell me that what data rate it receive and what is the sampling method of iphone SDK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can record sound (PCM samples) from the microphone to very short memory buffers (as short as a few milliseconds in duration).  That's as close to "live" as there is using iOS API's.  Look at the aurioTouch example for low latency AudioUnit RemoteIO recording code, with live FFT analysis and display.

Comment: So the Google app speech to text function, where you speak and see your words translate to text, after which the search is conducted on that, does it this way? (To be honest, there IS a lag between my speaking out and the text appearing, although I though this was due to server response taking time to come back, but now you are saying there is a very slight delay addition during the processing as well).

Comment: Is this still the case in 2019?  I want to create an app that changes the screen almost immediately after detecting a large amplitude change (saying "go" or clapping a hand or such).

If not is this possible with Android?

Comment: The display screen on most devices updates at a 60 Hz frame rate.  Thus some small multiple of 16.6 mS delay is as close to immediate at you can get (half that on the newest iPad Pros).

Answer (score 4):

Check this link:

http://code.google.com/p/ios-coreaudio-example/

Captures from Microphone & plays through speaker.